# Total.js Messenger, HTML Variables "@{...}"

Tags: html, frameworks, total.js

When I was looking the Total.js messenger sourcecode, I noticed the "@{...}" placeholder in the HTML markup.

https://github.com/totaljs/messenger/blob/master/views/index.html

What kind of placeholders are those? I would be thankfoul for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those placeholders are processed by [**Total.js Framework**](https://docs.totaljs.com/) View Engine.

See the documentaion here [https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#pages~View%20engine](https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#pages%7EView%20engine)